# the present simple or present perfect

Tags: grammar

1. The film is over
2. The film has been over

Do these 2 sentences have any difference or just the same meaning, use

Answer (score 2):

The film is over. [as of right now]

The film has been over since lunchtime. [as of some point in time, which is generally required for it to make sense].

Any event can be said to be over or have been over.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the first one. The second construction is rarely used for the word over.

Comment: Hi there! I saw that you have been making quite some contributions recently. It would be more helpful to the author of the question to have a an explanation rather than the general statement. You can post these as comments to the OP's post rather than an answer. Thanks!